# From txt files to grouped barplot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot data from 2 txt files 
**a.txt**

```
c(1009446997.10134, 2129582.232133, 1684766.791461, 1365519.983193, 
1162969.144628, 963505.413047, 806687.025846, 699778.395938, 
611536.669139, 558664.129031, 495161.162453, 416070.762165, 536345.97118, 
326020.411214, 323119.197493, 301553.888271, 276288.29474, 258147.28339, 
238231.281803, 221602.69459, 206269.189678, 186223.48747, 173136.239386, 
156750.406154, 289750.844258)
```

and **b.txt**

```
c(1006311544.86118, 2553892.687953, 2396309.164262, 1797103.229124, 
1435811.705459, 1123438.547316, 907066.016324, 752319.816852, 
633176.19432, 541055.716266, 456756.424805, 554325.764806, 335654.692806, 
320344.048214, 289641.383874, 268214.776278, 253511.851556, 240330.064774, 
231902.956644, 223549.91785, 229045.595197, 275974.717633, 1138710.866504
)
```

as a grouped barplot like this

[image]

Where the y axis are the values themselves and the x axis is the row number.
Notice that the number of rows is not the same in both files.

I'm trying this but without success

```
sfs_a<-(scan("a.txt")) #read in the log sfs
sfs_b<-(scan("b.txt")) #read in the log sfs
data <-list(sfs_a,sfs_b)
barplot(data, main="Proportions",
        xlab="Chromossomes", col=c("darkblue","red"), beside=TRUE)
```

Optional solution (but I'm sure very dumb one).

barplot(rbind(Non_synonymous = sfs_a[-1], Synonymous = c(sfs_wbm[-1], 0,0)), legend = TRUE, beside = TRUE, col = c('red', 'darkblue'), main = "Proportions")

[image]

Comment: Do you need `barplot(rbind(Non_synonymous = sfs_a, Synonymous = sfs_b), legend = TRUE, beside = TRUE, col = c('red', 'darkblue'), main = "Proportions")`

Comment: Thanks but it's distorted or something. :/ I'll ad the pic above.

Comment: I think i understand why you got it.  Please use `dput` to show the example.  You have vectors of unequal length

Comment: Yes. What you mean by use dput? Would you mind giving me an example? Thanks

Comment: dput(sfs_a) gives you a string that we just paste in R so we can have a data frame like yours

Comment: k. I did and pasted above. Is this what you meant? Thanks

Comment: I discovered I dont need the 1st value in each vector. So, when I do barplot(rbind(Non_synonymous = sfs_a[-1], Synonymous = sfs_b[-1]), legend = TRUE, beside = TRUE, col = c('red', 'blue')), I get the fig above.  The two last blue bars should not exist.

Comment: I ended up adding zeros to one vector. Produced the fig above. Which one would be the smarter way of doing this?